# How can I get common points of different point shapefiles in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlay

I have different data sets (point shapefile) and how can I get common point points of these shapefile in  ArcGIS?

Comment: See: [How To: Find duplicate or coincident features](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011323). What have you tried?

Comment: You can try Select by location tool with "are identical" spatial relationships

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to select them in the layer, the easiest way is to do it by using the "Select by location" tool. Choose both layers and select the "are identical"  relationship. That way you will get a selection that includes all points that are identical in both layers.

Additionally, if you want to get a layer that includes those points, after selecting them just right click on the layer, Data > Export Data > Only selected features.